# setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled Requires minimum SDK has to be 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I'm using Android Studio and in my OnCreate method within my apps project, I'm trying to enable the Up function on the action bar. It says it requires minSDk of 11 but mine is 9. I understand, I'm just wondering if there's a way to add this function with a minimum target of 9. I know there's a support library and if that has anything related with the Up function on the action bar.

Current way I'm enabling it

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: If your `minSdkVersion` is 9, then either you do not have an action bar on API Levels 9-10 (in which case, there is no "up"), or you are using an action bar backport (in which case, it will offer `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()`). The native action bar itself only exists on API Level 11+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ActionBarActivity` class and `getSupportActionBar` method of this class from android support library v7. See how to add it here [support v7](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).